# Is it possible to escape the <%= %>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Simple question, I'm new to Rails 3, if I have something like:

```
<% @array.each do |arr| %>
   <%= arr.thing %>
<% end %>
```

How would I escape it for cleanliness if I wanted to do something like this:

```
<% @array.each do |arr| %>
   <p><%= if arr.thing 'Read' else 'Unread' %></p> < All in 1 line prints whatever value to a <p></p>
<% end %>
```

So that I don't have to make even more clutter by going

```
<% @array.each do |arr| %>
   <%= if arr.thing %>
     <p>Read</p>
   <% else %>
     <p>Unread</p>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Is this possible, I tried googling Rails 3 ternary statements but I couldn't find aynthing like this that I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a string you don't need to escape it, and the ternary is as follows:

```
<p><%= arr.thing ? 'Read' : 'Unread' %></p>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question asked. However, I'd advise using a helper method, as using `if` statements like that can easily clutter views.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is best handled via a helper.

```
<p><%= read_or_unread(arr.thing) %>></p>
```

Helper:

```
class SomethingHelper
  def read_or_unread(thing)
    thing ? 'Read' : 'Unread'
  end
end
```

Where `read_or_unread` and `SomethingHelper` are more-meaningfully-named based on your domain.  You could also use the presenter pattern if you have additional complex logic.